# Unable to get the value when checkbox is checked in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table where header has a checkbox with SelectAll property and every row in the table has one checkbox ,both single and select all checkbox are working,now I am trying to get the Id value when it is checked ,but even if I disselect it,it is getting added to the array.

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

import "./styles.css";

const exampleData = [
  { Id: 1, Name: "name 1", Source: "source 1", Number: "number 1" },
  { Id: 2, Name: "name 2", Source: "source 2", Number: "number 2" },
  { Id: 3, Name: "name 3", Source: "source 3", Number: "number 3" },
  { Id: 4, Name: "name 4", Source: "source 4", Number: "number 4" },
  { Id: 5, Name: "name 5", Source: "source 5", Number: "number 5" }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectAll: false,
      items: exampleData.map(item => ({ ...item, checked: false }))
    };
  }
  selectAll = () => {
    this.setState({ selectAll: !this.state.selectAll }, () => {
var collection = [];
    for (const item of this.state.items) {
        collection.push(item.Id);
      }

      let items = [...this.state.items];
      items = items.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item,
          checked: this.state.selectAll
        };
      });
      this.setState({ items });
    });
  };
  handleTransClick = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You clicked row #" + id);
  };
  handleCheckbox = id => {
var collection2 = [];
collection2.push(id);
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item,
          checked: item.Id === id ? !item.checked : item.checked
        };
      })
    });
  };
  render() {
    const result = this.state.items;
    return (
      <Table striped bordered className="App">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="col-md-2">
              <input
                onChange={this.selectAll}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={this.state.selectAll}
              />
            </th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {result.map((item, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td className="col1">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name={item.Name}
                  checked={item.checked ? true : ""}
                  onChange={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this, item.Id)}
                />
              </td>
              <td className="col2">
                <a href="" onClick={e => this.handleTransClick(e, item.Id)}>
                  {item.Id}
                </a>
              </td>
              <td className="col3">{item.Name}</td>
              <td className="col4"> {item.Source}</td>
              <td className="col5"> {item.Number}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

How can I control them based on checked value of checkbox?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what the issue is. Which ID value are you talking about, and which array? What is happening that shouldn't be happening, or what is failing to happen that should be?

Comment: one thing that might help your issue is that you are passing an object to `this.setState` which references `this.state`. Such cases should be handled with a [function argument](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1) instead

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is....when I click on a certain checkbox,Id value associated with that checkbox should be added to a array.

Answer (score 0):

```
      else{

  this.setState({
    items : this.state.items.filter(function(val) {return val!==value})
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some irrelevant code at the start of your `handleCheckbox` method, but that's not going to stop it working. The only potential problem I see is that, due to the asynchronous nature of `setState`, you should use a function argument to `this.setState`:

```
handleCheckbox = id => {
  this.setState(state => {
    items: state.items.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      checked: item.Id === id ? !item.checked : item.checked
    }))
  });
};
```

Comment: I am not finding issue over there...what actually I am facing is...if I check on the checkbox of first row which contains fileds as Id,Name ,Source......it should give me the value ID which incase here is Id: 1

Comment: Yes, that's what your code should do (although you may well need the correction I've made). What do you mean by "it should give me the value ID" - can you please explain what is happening that's different from what you expect. (If it turns out it's a separate issue to my answer above, I'll delete it and hopefully replace with an answer to the real problem.)

Comment: Yes,sure  ...what I am facing now is I when the checkbox is checked ,Id value is added to the array...but even when it is unchecked it is added to array...how to prevent that?

Comment: as I said, the code you already have - especially with my correction above - should make sure the `checked` property for that item is `false` when the checkbox is clicked. Which should make the checkbox appear unchecked on the page. Are you saying that when you click to uncheck a checkbox, it stays checked? And is it still doing this with my modification shown in the answer?